# Multiple-input multiple-output model returns single value

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, lstm, keras-layer

I'm trying to get a forecast of customer revenues using both time-series (i.e. revenue in the past n months) and time-invariant customer data (i.e. gender, occupation) using a multiple-input model in Keras. To do so, I used an LSTM model to forecast the revenue at time (n+1) and then introduce the customer data as an auxiliary input.

The first model (LSTM) produced okay results but the addition of the auxiliary layer seem to create a paradox as every customer forecast is the same value. Any suggestion why this is happening?

Already tried multiple batch sizes and transforming some numeric variables but the problem persisted.

```
from keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Dense, concatenate
from keras.models import Model


'''
train_X1: time series data, customer revenues, 1 to (n-1)
train_X2: customer demographics
'''


train_X1 = np.asarray(X1.drop('id', axis = 1))
train_X1 = train_X1.reshape(train_X1.shape[0], train_X1.shape[1], 1)
print(train_X1.shape)

train_X2 = np.asarray(X2.drop('id', axis = 1))
print(train_X2.shape)


main_input = Input(shape = (20,1), name = "main_input")
hidden = Dense(10, activation = 'tanh')(main_input)
hidden = LSTM(10)(hidden)
aux_output = Dense(1, name = 'aux_output')(hidden)

train_X2 = np.asarray(X2.drop('id', axis = 1))
train_X2 = train_X2.reshape(train_X2.shape[0], train_X2.shape[1])
print(train_X2.shape)

aux_input = Input(shape = (2, ), name = "aux_input")
hidden = concatenate([aux_output, aux_input])
hidden = Dense(2, activation = 'relu')(hidden)
main_output = Dense(1, name = "main_output")(hidden)

model = Model(inputs = [main_input, aux_input], outputs = [main_output, aux_output])

model.compile(optimizer ='adam',
              loss = {'main_output': 'mean_squared_error', 'aux_output': 'mean_squared_error'},
              loss_weights = {'main_output': 1, 'aux_output': 0.2})
model.fit({'main_input': train_X1, 'aux_input': train_X2},
                {'main_output': y, 'aux_output': y},
                epochs = 50, batch_size = 5)
```

Expecting varying forecast but this code only resulted to a single value predcition. (see image)

**Note:** I'm current only simulating this work in a very small dataset before I can scale it to a larger set. Could this be a data issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you do

`preds = model.predict([train_X1, train_X2])`

you will get a list of two numpy arrays.

If the shape of `train_X1` is `(100, 20, 1)` and shape of `train_X2` is `(100, 2)` your `preds` will be a list of two numpy arrays, where each array is of shape `(100, 1)`.

You can access prediction for test sample `i` like this

`preds[0][i], preds[1][i]`

You can loop over the arrays to get the output for each sample for visual verification like this

```
preds = model.predict([train_X1, train_X2])
for i in range(len(preds[1])):
    print(f'Main prediction for sample {i} = {preds[0][i]} --- Aux Prediction for sample {i} = {preds[1][i]}')


# Output

Main prediction for sample 0 = [-5.820766e-09] --- Aux Prediction for sample 0 = [-9.313226e-09]
Main prediction for sample 1 = [-5.820766e-09] --- Aux Prediction for sample 1 = [-9.313226e-09]
Main prediction for sample 2 = [-5.820766e-09] --- Aux Prediction for sample 2 = [-9.313226e-09]
Main prediction for sample 3 = [-5.820766e-09] --- Aux Prediction for sample 3 = [-9.313226e-09]
Main prediction for sample 4 = [-5.820766e-09] --- Aux Prediction for sample 4 = [-9.313226e-09]
..................................................................................................
```